# BlazoredLocalStorage secretly fails to register?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, dependency-injection, blazor

I've created a .NET8 Blazor project (a client and server side) and added the Blazored.LocalStorage nuget package for the client side. In the `Program.cs` file I'm adding the service registration line:

```
builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
```

Then, on a page where I want to use it I inject the instance with:

```
@inject ILocalStorageService _localStorage
```

Unfortunately, when I start the webapp, I see the error in the browser:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property
> '_localStorage' on type 'MyProject.Client.Pages.Login'. There is no registered
> service of type 'Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your page? Where is the injection being setup? What render mode are you using?

Comment: The page is in the client side. DI setup is in project's Program.cs. I don't remember the rendering mode. I think it was Global. How can I check that to make sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if you are using global rendermode or not, you could open the "server project" -Components- App.razor.
Global:

```
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveWebAssembly" />
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveWebAssembly" />
```

Per page: you need to manually add `@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly` at any top of each page. (When you don't add, it only use server-side-rendering)

```
    <HeadOutlet />
    <Routes />
```

> There is no registered service of type 'Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService'.

You need to add `builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();` to both server project and client project. This is because  `@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly` will still prerender on server 1st. The prerender SSR(server-side rendering) is executed in the server project .

But as SSR actually cannot access localstorage at all. You will need to disable prerender. To do this:
If you are using global rendermode, change the App.razor like

```
    <Routes @rendermode="new InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode(false)" />
```

If you are using per component, add rendermode at top of page like

```
@rendermode @(new InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode(false))
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#prerendering

Comment: One more question - do I have to register all my services on both the client and the server side? Will I need to create a shared project just for that?

Comment: Other then that, your solutions worked and I do seem to be using the Global rendermode. Thanks.

Comment: @val That depends what rendermode this page will use,  (SSR or Server: need register in server) (Webassembly: need register in client).  And when you doesn't disable prerender, you will need always register on server.   I don't think there's a "shared project solution" for this.